# Yocto apt config sources.list

Tags: apt, deb, yocto, debian-based, openembedded

I have been trying lately to set up a package feed from my host machine for the yocto distrib running on a qemu on the host machine.

I added as told "apt" to the IMAGE_INSTALL and added the package-managment in the EXTRA_FEATURE

Then I setted up an Apache 2 http server with the following the config:

```
Alias /deb ~/yocto/build-qemuarm/tmp-glibc/deploy/deb
<Directory "~/yocto/build-qemuarm/tmp-glibc/deploy/deb">
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Then I tried without success to set up the sources.list on the target (qemu)

I looked over the Internet but no way to find a concrete example for apt set-up, only for ipk/rpm. I don't see how to set up the mandatory suite option and components.

Here is the listing of the deploy/deb dir without all the *.dev packages:

```
tree -I *.deb
.
--- all
   | Packages
   | Packages.gz
   | Release
--- armv5te
   | Packages
   | Packages.gz
   | Release
--- qemuarm
   | Packages
   | Packages.gz
   | Release
```

Here is my sources.list up to now:

```
deb http://192.168.7.1:8000/all all all
```

Here is the log of apt-get update :

```
root@qemuarm:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get update 
Ign http://192.168.7.1:8000 all InRelease
Ign http://192.168.7.1:8000 all Release.gpg
Ign http://192.168.7.1:8000 all Release
Err http://192.168.7.1:8000 all/all armel Packages
  404  File not found
Ign http://192.168.7.1:8000 all/all Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://192.168.7.1:8000/all/dists/all/all/binary-armel/Packages  404  File not found



E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@qemuarm:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get update
Err http://192.168.7.1:8000 all InRelease

Err http://192.168.7.1:8000 all Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 192.168.7.1:8000:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://192.168.7.1:8000/all/dists/all/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://192.168.7.1:8000/all/dists/all/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.7.1:8000:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried for my sources.list:

```
deb http://192.168.7.1:8000 all
```

But got:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oe.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

So if anybody got more debian package experience than me, and/or has already tried to do the same as me, I would be happy yo have some clues.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By default apt expects a more complex directory structure but adding a '/' to the suite name should tell it that what we have is just a simple directory:

```
deb http://192.168.7.1:8000/ all/
deb http://192.168.7.1:8000/ armv5te/
```